# Parallelly looping over different lengths

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

The idea is while iterating over a dictionary variable's each key, to take the first integer from each key, then in the next iteration, each key's second integer should be taken from the list, then only the third integer from each key, and so on.

I have the desired output, however, I would like to make it as universal as possible. Meaning that, instead of a static index order application, I would like two parallel loops. (probably izip is the solution)

My code:

```
dictionary = {0:[9, 9, 10, 8, 8, 8, 8], 1: [12,9,8,9,9,6,7], 2:[12, 12, 12, 10, 8, 9, 6], 3:[11, 10, 9, 12, 11, 10, 9]}

horizontal_dict = {}      
l1 = [] 
l2 = [] 
l3 =[] 
l4 = [] 
l5 =[] 
l6= []
l7 = []
for i in range(len(dictionary)):
    l1.append(dictionary[i][0])
    l2.append(dictionary[i][1])
    l3.append(dictionary[i][2])
    l4.append(dictionary[i][3])
    l5.append(dictionary[i][4])
    l6.append(dictionary[i][5])
    l7.append(dictionary[i][6])
    
    horizontal_dict[1] = l1
    horizontal_dict[2] = l2
    horizontal_dict[3] = l3
    horizontal_dict[4] = l4
    horizontal_dict[5] = l5
    horizontal_dict[6] = l6
    horizontal_dict[7] = l7
```

Result of dictionary:

```
dictionary
Out[38]: 
{0: [9, 9, 10, 8, 8, 8, 8],
 1: [12, 9, 8, 9, 9, 6, 7],
 2: [12, 12, 12, 10, 8, 9, 6],
 3: [11, 10, 9, 12, 11, 10, 9]}
```

Desired result:

```
horizontal_dict
Out[37]: 
{1: [9, 12, 12, 11],
 2: [9, 9, 12, 10],
 3: [10, 8, 12, 9],
 4: [8, 9, 10, 12],
 5: [8, 9, 8, 11],
 6: [8, 6, 9, 10],
 7: [8, 7, 6, 9]}
```

Comment: `itertools.zip_longest()`?

Comment: probably something like that but in my case if you look at the code, since itertools.zip_longest produces "none" values in order to make up the difference, the list indices with ['none'] values will result in error. @JohnColeman

Comment: how did you decide there are seven lists?

Comment: with a custom function that takes that integer input as a paramater, which calculates the iterations from a dataframe that's stored but has to be rotated in the right manner as I've explained in the code solution/example above. @python_user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use loops:

```
dictionary = {
    0: [9, 9, 10, 8, 8, 8, 8],
    1: [12, 9, 8, 9, 9, 6, 7],
    2: [12, 12, 12, 10, 8, 9, 6],
    3: [11, 10, 9, 12, 11, 10, 9, 13]
}

new = {}

for n in range(max(len(v) for v in dictionary.values())):
    new[n] = []
    for k, lst in dictionary.items():
        if n < len(lst):
            new[n].append(lst[n])
        else:
            # no element at index n
            # use a default value!
            new[n].append(-1)

print(new)
```

Out:

```
{0: [9, 12, 12, 11],
 1: [9, 9, 12, 10],
 2: [10, 8, 12, 9],
 3: [8, 9, 10, 12],
 4: [8, 9, 8, 11],
 5: [8, 6, 9, 10],
 6: [8, 7, 6, 9],
 7: [-1, -1, -1, 13]}
```

Comment: This answer is legit! I'll accept it if nobody gives any other tip or another way of solving it. Thanks @Maurice Meyer !

Answer (score 1):

you can do that in just one line :

```
dictionary = {0:[9, 9, 10, 8, 8, 8, 8], 1: [12,9,8,9,9,6,7], 2:[12, 12, 12, 10, 8, 9, 6], 3:[11, 10, 9, 12, 11, 10, 9]} 
horizontal_dict={key:list(data) for data,key in zip(zip(*dictionary.values()),dictionary.keys())}
```